# c++ taking input from user and executing command

Tags: c++, user-input

Ok so lets say we have 3 text files named: `henry.txt`  `adam.txt`  `josh.txt`

We want to open these text files, read the contents and store the integers contained in the text files into an array.

So for example `henry.txt` contains the integers: `100, 200, 300, 400, 500` all on a different line.

Now as for taking input from the user, lets say the user types: `Start Henry`

This would read the text file and store the integers on each line into an array.

Then the user could type: `Select k`, which would print out the kth item in the array. Or the user could type `Select max` which would print the last element in the array.

Lastly the user types: `End henry`
This closes the file and frees any dynamically allocated memory.

I already know how to write the code for taking the integers in the text files and storing them into an array and so forth.

What I am confused on is how I would implement things such as `Start henry` `Select k` and `End henry`.

For `Start henry` I tried using `std::string::find` to check if the word "Start" was contained in the string that stores input from the user. If "Start" is found then it calls the function `Start()`. From here it again checks if a word such as henry, josh, or adam is contained within the input the user entered. If one of the words is found then it opens the text file associated with the name and stores the integers into an array.

Now I dont know if there is a better way to do this, but if there is please explain it to me.

My real problem here is when the user enters `Select k`. I tried implementing the same method I did with `Start` but I have no clue as to how I would check if a certain element in the array was entered, or if `max` was entered instead.

Comment: Please don't explain code in prose. Post a minimal sample of your real code, that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when you check if first six letters of the command are "Select" you can use method [substr()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to return the numbers the user wrote, as in:

```
std::string numAsString = command.substr(7);
```

Keep in mind, if user writes "Select 123 " (with a space at the end), your string `numAsString` will have a space aswell!

Next step would be parsing string to an integer, and you can use atoi for that (to be honest, I can't think of another way, there probably has to be one...). My idea is:

```
int num = atoi(numAsString.c_str());
```

And later compare it with the length of array and.. whatever else you want to do.